# PHP/PDO - Best way to loop through an array and adding it to a database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am taking data from a CSV file and adding it to an array, in order for me to save it to my database. This is the array format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product code
            [1] => Product text
            [2] => Stockcode
            [3] => Origin
            [4] => Batchnumber
            [5] => Quantity
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02-018              
            [1] => TEMPCELL13 TIF 120 HOUR 6P/P  
            [2] => OK1
            [3] =>    
            [4] =>                  
            [5] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02-038              
            [1] => TEMPCELL60 TIF 120 HOUR(BROWN)
            [2] => OK1
            [3] =>    
            [4] =>                  
            [5] => 15
        )
)
```

Where, `$data[0]` is the same name as my columns in my database:

[image]

So, I want to loop through all arrays, but skipping `$data[0]`, and add this to my database. This is what I currently have:

```
function process_csv($file) {

    $file = fopen($file, "r");
    $data = array();

    while (!feof($file)) {
        $data[] = fgetcsv($file,null,';');
    }

    fclose($file);

    unset($data[0]); //Unset the header information, since we only want the values to parse into our inventory database. $data[0] contains the header from the CSV = columns in our database
    foreach($data as $insert){

    //Insert $data to my database
    // $insert[] now holds the array

    }

}
```

What would be the best way to loop through each array and add it? Furthermore, if the "`product_code`" is already present in the database, it should just `UPDATE` that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could drop the `foreach` statement and move your logic directly in the `while` loop:

```
$header = true;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $data = fgetcsv($file,null,';');

    // skip the first line
    if ($header) {
        $header = false;
    }
    else {
        //Insert $data to my database
    }
}
```

Otherwise you're looping twice (`while` to read the file line by line and `foreach` to loop the array) and consuming too much memory to build the array to loop through.

For the SQL, you can use a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Consuming "too much memory"? How so?

Comment: Because you're building an entire array; instead just reuse a single variable.

Comment: Down when I do the inserting into the database, should I use the array like: $data[0], $data[1], $data[2] etc.?

Comment: If I use the array like this, to insert into the database: $stmt->bindParam(":product_code", $data[0]); - I get that "Column 'product_code' cannot be null"

Comment: `$data` inside the `while` loop will look like `Array
(
    [0] => 02-038              
    [1] => TEMPCELL60 TIF 120 HOUR(BROWN)
    [2] => OK1
    [3] =>    
    [4] =>                  
    [5] => 15
)`

Comment: Also, check the value of `$data[0]` and make sure the format **02-018** is accepted by your field in the database. If your `product_code` in the database is `int` or `varchar`, this will most likely not work as expected.